# Create an alias of the script by calling the script with an argument: ./myscript alias

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to be able to create an alias of my script by calling it with an argument.

```
$ ./devbox alias
$ devbox <other command of my script>
```

Here is the code of my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s expand_aliases

aliasDevbox()
{  
  alias devbox="./devbox"
}

parseCli()
{
  command=$1

  case "$command" in
    "alias") aliasDevbox
    ;;
  esac
}

parseCli "$@"
```

It's actually not working: `command not found`

(I know that if my code `alias devbox="./devbox"` was at the beginning of my script, I would be able to call it this way `source ./devbox` and it would work.)

Thank you!

Comment: It's not the script's job to set how someone can call it; that's either a deployment issue or the responsibility of the particular user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't and can't work because `./devbox` is a child process of your shell, and child processes can't set aliases in parent shells. (Similarly, they can't change environment variables either.)

I can suggest workarounds, but taking a step back, is this really needed? Typically, users will set up aliases in a login script such as `.bashrc` so that the aliases are automatically available in any new shell they start. My suggestion is simply to write some documentation suggesting that users create an alias for your tool to make it easier to use.